# Differential of a complex 1-form

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

for a complex number $z$ consider the following 1-form $\omega=\frac{dz}{z}$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$. One can show that it is closed by explicitely calculating the differentials of the real and imaginary part of the following decomposition:

$$\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{d(x+iy)}{x+iy}=\frac{(x-iy)(dx+idy)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$$.

I would like to ask if the following shortcut is appropiate:

$d\omega=d(\frac{1}{z}) \wedge dz=\partial_z (\frac{1}{z})dz\wedge dz=0$, where I use $df=\partial_zf(z)dz$ with $\partial_z=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$ in the second-last equation.

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the $1$-form ${dz\over z}$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$ closed?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781719/why-is-the-1-form-dz-over-z-on-mathbbc-closed)